# Is there a Scratch script or function that can detect the angle of a wall?

Tags: mit-scratch

Im working on a 2D, non-scrolling, portal-themed platformer in scratch, and I was wondering if there was a function or script that I could make to help find the angle of a wall. As it stands, the portals do "stick" to the walls, but I want them to be perfectly level with the wall.

(link to the project for more details, its still in development: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/899664020/)

Also, I have some coding knowledge, so if your answer isn't in a scratch coding language, but is still compatible with it, I can most likely decipher it.

I haven't tried anything yet, mostly because I don't know what to do, or how to accomplish it. I did try googling for some similar questions/answers but got nothing.

EDIT: I think what I'm looking for is a form of raycasting, so It can detect any angle without having to do any manual work.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand exactly what is the `wall` you are talking about, and how it is specified in your code.

I will assume that you can find the `slope` of that wall. You can get the angle from there using [arcsine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) function. It's called `asin` in Scratch.

Comment: the "wall" is actually one entire sprite (and I think I have it named as "level" in the project), Incase that helps.

Comment: @toastypixelcrisps Is it `Sprite2`? That's the only angle I can find :) Did you draw it by hand? At what angle?

Comment: Oh, my bad, the level is under "sprite 3" I was wondering if there could be something of like an instantaneous rotation that kind of "maps" out what the wall "looks" like, then calculates what angle it needs to be at.

Comment: @toastypixelcrisps all walls in `Sprite 3` looks like the right angle, 90 degrees. I am sorry, I don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: No you're good. At least you tried. But if you know anyone who is more experienced with something like this, please inform them of my troubles and see if they can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:
https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/939684578/
I didn't put it in run without screen refresh so that you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to create a base wall element (could be a simple line), then orient it near surfaces where you want your portal to stick.

Then, you can broadcast an event on a hit, and store the hit object's orientation value in a variable. The newly created portal can read the last set orientation value.

Demo for broadcasting: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/966207615